# In an MVC view, what controller and method is called if none is specified in the form tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I have a MVC project I inherited.  On the views, there's no route (controller and action) specified in the BeginForm tag.  The view renders correctly so I assume it is picking a default route.

My question is how does it know what route to use if one isn't specified?  What's the best practice here: should you specify a route or let it default?

So the view is Views/Config/WorkCodes.cshtml and the tag is

```
Html.BeginForm()
```

It goes to the controller ConfigController.cs and calls action WorkCodes().  If I was doing the project, I would have wrote

```
Html.BeginForm("WorkCodes", "Config", FormMethod.Post)
```

How does MVC know which controller and action to use without specifying it?

WorkCodes.cshtml

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Work Codes";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    <table style="width: 100%;" class="trHoverHighlight">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <button id="buttonCreateNew" type="button">Add New</button>&nbsp;
                        <button id="buttonReturn" type="button">Return</button>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

}

ConfigController.cs

```
    public ActionResult WorkCodes()
    {
        return View(Rep.GetWorkAll(true));
    }
```

Here's where the view is called from in another view:

```
                @foreach (var itm in (List<string>)ViewBag.ListObjects)
                {
                        <li>
                            <a href="../Config/@itm">Work Codes</a>
                        </li>  
                }
```

Comment: The default `FormMethod` is `FormMethod.Post` and the default controller and action names are the ones that generated the view (from the GET method)

Comment: [It's in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244(v=vs.118).aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The View is generated from performing `HTTP GET` to the `WorkCodes` controller action, thus by default the form generated in that view performs an `HTTP POST` to a controller action with the same name.

[Here's the MSDN docs.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> BeginForm(HtmlHelper) Writes an opening  tag to the response.
>   The form uses the POST method, and the request is processed by the
>   action method for the view.

Comment: So what's a best practice for this?  Specifying the route or not specifying the route?

Comment: Not specifying the values means less code and means you can't make a typo when typing the magic strings for the action and controller names

Comment: Usually folks don't specify it if you're not routing somewhere other than the default location (The Controller\Action) that's already mapped to the view. Sometimes you may want to route out to a different controller/action on a given post, and at that point it would be appropriate to add the route specifically.